# My Magento Contact page does not show the Submit Button

Tags: magento-1.9

I need some help with my small but annoying problem.

While testing my new Magento website, I realised that in my contact page the SUBMIT button is not showing, and so the contact form can not be sent

I have tried with Safari, Chrome, Firefox all the same...

Please check it here:
http://www.stampaoffsetonline.com/weprint/contacts/

How can I solve this problem?

Any indication would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have css issue,

**Submit button background** color is  **transparent**.so it deos not visible

Add this css on css file

```
.contacts-index-index .buttons-set .button { background: #3072b3}
```

Open *skin/frontend/printshop/default/css/template.css* goto line  451
this css property `background: #3072b3`

Comment: Hi Amit, 
Thank you for your help. 
It worked!!!